# Show special chars like é in AutoComplete

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding, ajaxcontroltoolkit, webmethod

How do I show special chars like é in Ajax Control Toolkit's AutoComplete? They're showing as a white square in IE7 and a black diamond in FF4. I tried escaping them in the WebMethod using HttpUtility.HtmlEncode but that made it worse!

(Also raised here http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/26998)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading the values in from file, use

```
StreamReader re = new StreamReader(filepath,System.Text.Encoding.UTF7);
```

rather than

```
StreamReader re = new StreamReader(filepath);
```